# Prevent Jquery dialog to close on Page Load

Tags: asp.net

My Jquery Dialog calls .ascx page.Problem is,on each and every time PageLoad of .ascx.cs,it closes the dialog.I added

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", "loadModal(" + id + ");", true);
```

to open modal again but I want to remove this script from code and want data update without post-back and keep dialog opens.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: And hint: your priorities are **your** problems. I suggest you edit your question *asap*. What is the point of having *please* followed by *asap* in the first place?!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use update panel with UpdateMode="Conditional"

So that when you go to server side it will not update your whole page instead it will update content inside your modal only so that way modal will not be closed.

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updModal" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:Button ID="TestButton" runat="server" Text="Test Button" onclick="TestButton_Click" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>         
        </ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", "loadModal(" + id + ");", true);
        }
```